# regex for comma separated valid mobile numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found following regex that can validate multiple email addresses (comma separated)

```
/^(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+\s?,)*(\s?[^\s,]+@[^\s,]+\.[^\s,]+)$/
```

I also have this regex that can check for valid Indian mobile numbers, ie. 10 digit numeric starting with [6,7,8 or 9] only

```
/[6-9]{1}\d{9}/
```

I am looking for a regex that can test a comma separated list of mobile numbers.

```js
let mobilePattern = /[6-9]{1}\d{9}/;
console.log(mobilePattern.test('8223822382')); // valid
console.log(mobilePattern.test('3223822382')); // invalid start with 3
console.log(mobilePattern.test('823822382')); // invalid 9 digits
```

Comment: Do you accept spaces before/after a comma?

Comment: no spaces required

Comment: Your regex works for your tests. What is your question exactly?

Answer (score 3):

Yo can try with this:

```
/[6-9]\d{9}(,[6-9]\d{9})*/
```

If you wants that contains exactly that format you can try:

```
/^[6-9]\d{9}(,[6-9]\d{9})*$/
```